# Adding a movie to a user's list of favourites in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently learning full-stack development and I'm having trouble on a task where I have to insert a movie ID into a users list of favourites using Mongodb.

The user I've created is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e1501c6abeeaf482847d46e"),
    "UserName": "JulijaDa",
    "Password": "FwPreviledges",
    "Email": "Julija.Da@live.ru",
    "Birhday": {
        "$date": "1995-03-16T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "Favs":[
        {
         "ObjectId": "5e1352793e9e6a804448db0c"
        }
    ]
}
```

This user currently has only one favourite movie **(5e1352793e9e6a804448db0c)** and I need to add another **(5e1352793e9e6a804448db0e)** but, using this method:

```
db.user.update({
    "UserName": "JulijaDa"
}, {
    $push: {
        "Favs": ObjectId("5e1352793e9e6a804448db0e")
    }
})
```

Mongo returns:

```
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 0, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 0 })
```

I'm following the instructions but, honestly, I'm starting to pull my hair out over here. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can also provide more information if needed but, this is basically all I have right now!

Thank you in advance

Comment: When I tried, I got this: `WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })`.  The issues I found are: (1) `"$date"` field name was illegal , and (2) the update adds a `ObjectId("5e1352793e9e6a804448db0e")`, _not_ `{ ObjectId: "5e1352793e9e6a804448db0c" }` as you intended (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through a lot of trial and error, it seems the required code to add a favourite to his user in the database is:

```
db.[collection name].update(
    { _id: ObjectId("[ID of item being updated]") },
    { $push: { [Name of key]: { [value being added] } } }
)
```

In the above example, it would look like this:

```
db.users.update(
    { _id: ObjectId("5e1501c6abeeaf482847d46e") },
    { $push: { Favs: { ObjectId: "5e1352793e9e6a804448db0e" } } }
)
```

This will added the correct value to the correct fields.
I hope this helps other who are struggling too.